# Multi List Column is not align properly in android when i retrive data from sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

i am using multi column list view for display data from SQLite in my android Project. but when i view the list activity the column is not showing properly that i have set.
my code is here.

grid_item.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView 
      android:id="@+id/item1"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:layout_margin="5dp" 
      android:text="date"/>  

    <TextView 
      android:id="@+id/item2"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="2" 
      android:textStyle="bold"
      android:layout_margin="5dp" 
      android:text="Particuler"/>

    <TextView 
      android:id="@+id/item3"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="0.7"
      android:layout_margin="5dp" 
      android:textColor="#26BF2A"
      android:gravity="right"
      android:text="income" />

    <TextView 
      android:id="@+id/item4"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="0.7"
      android:layout_margin="5dp" 
      android:textColor="#F86F5C"
      android:gravity="right"
      android:text="expenses" />
    <TextView 
      android:id="@+id/item5"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="0.7"
      android:layout_margin="5dp" 
      android:gravity="right"
      android:text="closing" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Report_View.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- Header -->
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        >
        <TextView android:id="@+id/item1"
            android:text="Date"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp" 
            android:layout_weight="1"
        />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/item2"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="Particuler"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp" 
            android:layout_weight="2"
        />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/item3"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="Income"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_margin="5dp" 
            android:layout_weight="0.7"
        />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/item4"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="Expenses"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp" 
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="0.7"
        />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/item5"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="Closing"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp" 
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="0.7"
        />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- List Divider -->
    <View android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:background="?android:attr/listDivider" />

    <!-- ListView (grid_items) -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="184dp" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_view"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="189dp" >

        </ListView>

    </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/list_vi"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:text="Next"/>

        </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

when i run the the column of list is not properly by width.
list screen shot is here
[List View Activity ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDNjk.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the `width` of the layout containing the results to `match_parent` :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="184dp" >
```

Comment: Glad I could help :)